# SugarCRM database sessions

Tags: php, session, sugarcrm

I am trying to move my *PHP* sessions in *SugarCRM* from the *filesystem* to the *database*.

Has anyone attempted this?

I have *SugarCRM* running on a *LAMP* stack.

I have attempted to make use of the `session_set_save_handler` method but since making my updates I am no longer able to log in. I'm assuming that this is because the *SugarCRM* config file specifies a file location for sessions and my sessions are no longer there.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: @pringi This was a well phrased question clearly asking how to move sessions from the filesystem to the database.  The bulk of your edits (italicization of some words) did nothing to improve the readability of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by making use of the session_set_save_handler method and my own custom session class. I simply had to ensure that I made calls to this before all session_start calls in sugarcrm.